# What's the difference between app_data folder in web application and in web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, web

I want to ask what the difference is between the `app_data` folder in a **web application** and in a **web site** .

I want to make sure that this folder is secure in web application because I put specific file in this folder which specific users only can download it.

Comment: How are you providing the provision to download the file? Is there any GridView and contains Hyperlinks? Second Question is - How are you differentiating downloading process for users?

Comment: just a hyperlink in a widget this widget appears only for specific users according to field in my db ..but i wanna to make sure that this folder is secure enough . when i published i had to copy and paste this folder to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preventive Action to check the user is valid before downloading

1. Do not give the `Directory Browsing` Provision in `IIS`.
2. There is basically a way in which the `Anonymous/Unauthorized` user can Access/download your `Authorized File`. **Example** - You know the `Query String` Values and other user can type and download it. So, there are two ways by which you can prevent unauthorized User to download file.

   (a) Keep the `Web.Config` in this folder and define the `Roles/Users` whoever can access it.

   (b) In the `Page Load`, you can check the page being opened is being done by the `Authorized user` only.

---

`App_Data` Folder is same for both types `Web Application` as well as `Web Site`.

Answer (score 3):

The App_Data folder is used by ASP.NET to store an application's local database, such as the database for maintaining membership and role information.  There is be no difference between the app_data folder using a Web App or a Web Site.

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Darren answered, there is no difference.

But to your other point of using it as a secure storage location, it is protected by ASP.NET, much like the bin folder, and users cannot browse to it.